# Getting Manifest merger failed Error While Updating Places Api

Tags: android, android-studio, android-maps

Hey My Google Places Api Was Not Working And i  see in The Log They Asked To Updated Places Api .. So I tried To Do So They Asked to Add Few Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.2.0'
```

When I Add Both These Dependencies Then i Get This Errror

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@theme value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteThemeOverlay) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-66 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-61 value=(@style/PlacesAutocompleteOverlay). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 20 Error: Attribute activity#com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity@windowSoftInputMode value=(stateAlwaysVisible|adjustPan) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:13-71 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-55 value=(adjustResize). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:windowSoftInputMode"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:16:9-23:20 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 21
```

But if i Add Only one Dependency Then its Work Okay Bu I Need Both These Dependencies in the code Please Help am trying to solve it for past 4 hours  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's documentation version **2.0.0** of the Places SDK for Android now depends on AndroidX.  In order to retain compatibility, you must migrate your projects to use AndroidX.

You should remove one of those implementation

```
com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0

com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.2.0
```

depending on what you want to do you have to choose the library you want to implement

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration